# Send pdf from pikepdf as BytesIO stream - flask send_file content length mismatch

Tags: python, flask, pikepdf

I am trying to send a pdf as an api response using Flask. However, I get a `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` on the client side of the api.
Maybe this is caused by the stream not being complete while the file is send to the client? Idk

```
from flask import Flask, send_file, make_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def get_pdf(request):
    # Set CORS headers for the preflight request
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        # Allows GET requests from any origin with the Content-Type
        # header and caches preflight response for an 3600s
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        return ('', 204, headers)

    pdf = Pdf.open('test.pdf')
    file = io.BytesIO()
    pdf.save(file)

    response = make_response(send_file(file, download_name="project_pdf", mimetype='application/pdf', as_attachment=True))
    response.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

    return response
```

Comment: Complete guess, but perhaps you need to rewind the stream before passing it to `send_file`, so right after `pdf.save(file)` do `file.seek(0)` then proceed to build the response.

Comment: What actually worked for me was to do `send_file(io.BytesIO(file.getbuffer()))`. I know this is kind of a hack though :)